# cURL Proxy issues 407

Tags: php, curl, proxy

The Following gives me a 407 error, Can anyone see why or where I'm going wrong?
I am behind a proxy.
I have spent a while on this.
I'm using the correct credentials.
Thanks

```
function pushMeTo($widgeturl,$text,$signature) {
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.12) Gecko/2009070611 Firefox/3.0.12";
    if (!function_exists("curl_init")) die("pushMeTo needs CURL module, please install CURL on your php.");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $widgeturl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'user:pass');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "IP");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    $page = curl_exec($ch); //or die("Curl exe failed"); 
    print_r(curl_error($ch));
    print_r($page);
    preg_match("/form action=\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $form_action);
    preg_match("/textarea name=\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $message_field);
    preg_match("/input type=\"text\" name=\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $signature_field);
    //print_r($message_field);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $strpost = $message_field[1].'=' . urlencode($text) . '&'.$signature_field[1].'=' . urlencode($signature);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strpost );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $form_action[1]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
}




?>

<?

$url = "MY URL";
 pushmeTo ($url,"This Is A Test","ServiceDesk");

?>
```

Comment: wat version of curl do you have..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to add:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
```

After that everything worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP'); // just a guess
```

If this does not work for you then check if mod_proxy apache module is loaded or not.
If thats also loaded , then try recompiling curl module using latest version
Hope it helps you in debugging.

Comment: Thanks but didn't work, I think I'm running 5.3.5.0 (php_curl.dll properties)
Adding that line didn't change anything, mod proxy is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check the bottom, where you use the function.  Should have a capitol M.