# Script executing fine on browser failing on cli

Tags: php, proxy, command-line-interface, guzzle

So, I am in CentOS 7, and I have a script that basically connects to an AWS machine checks for new files and downloads them. Running it through the browser works perfectly, yet I want it to be a cron job, so I am trying to run it on the command line but it fails with the following message:-

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException: [curl] 56: Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT
```

I already tested, and the same modules ( checked by `get_loaded_extensions( )` ) are being loaded in both cases, the same user is executing the script (checked by `get_current_user( )` ) and the phpinfo loaded is the same file in both cases;

I am behind a corporate proxy, but I can't see why this does not affect the process running through Apache but affects the one running on the CLI.

We are talking about the exact same file being executed. So I am trying to understand what Apache is doing to be able to get to the proxy, and why is it failing on the CLI, any tips on what I could/should check next?

This question is not a duplicate of [cURL Proxy issues 407](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313059/curl-proxy-issues-407) . Read the answer to verify that both cases are not the same.

Comment: When you get a `407 Proxy Authentication Required`, then I think your best bet is to talk to the proxy admin ...

Comment: Thank you for answering, I do understand that, but, why would I be getting an error through the CLI but passing through apache, that is what I am trying to debug here.

Comment: I would not waste time on debugging here before talking to the proxy admin ... might in the end turn out that they simply configured the proxy to let requests originating from Apache through without further hassle.

Comment: Unfortunately that is a luxury I can't incur in.

According to the proxy admin, if it is working in one of the cases and I do not have a reason for it not to be working, then the error is in my side. Hence why I would like to understand what could be happening to be able to check it with him.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL Proxy issues 407](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313059/curl-proxy-issues-407)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there is one thing that I forgot to say and now I realize that it is probably the problem here.

This script is in a server on my network, but not on my computer.

Which means that when I see the script running on my browser my system credentials are hitting the proxy, when I run it on the command line of the server, the server credentials hit the proxy instead... since I am not giving any credentials to guzzle the proxy is not authenticating the request.

Sorry for wasting your time.